# Laravel HasOne relation is eager loading all models into memory rather than the specified oldest()

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to load the next due appointment from a relation. The relation is HasMany so my function looks like this:

```
public function nextAppointment(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Appointment::class, 'some_model_id')
        ->whereNull('completed_at')
        ->oldest('starts_at');
}
```

This is working fine however, locally, I have debugdhbar installed and the SQL query this is doing is a where in. This results in ALL the appointments being eager loaded into memory and I end up seeing that over 100 appointments are being loaded for a simple check against the latest. The SQL looks like this:

```
select * from "appointments" where "completed_at" is null and "appointments"."some_model_id" in ('00cb2664-2aec-4600-a3ca-873dbb5f81f3', '04b62cc7-9ec7-4613-af13-3bc53f9b3538', '109fce77-0fd4-4478-b30d-0c95468d1037', '11b28a27-020d-46f8-b498-51ec152192a2', '11dee373-ec59-4804-897e-2bc5094a3785', '15614002-2414-488d-b639-6410f1c32004', '19d43627-10c5-4708-861d-9394a6ee9b69', 'fffc6b29-fbac-4b6a-80bf-781a2e720c38') order by "starts_at" asc
```

How can I optimize this relation so it only loads the latest appointment into memory? The controller looks like this:

```
return SomeModel::with(['nextAppointment'])->paginate(request()->input('size', 10));
```

Comment: Try adding an order by and desc  before paginate

Comment: Just a query: If Appointment table is supposed to have only 1 record, why would be more records fetched for a particular ID?

Comment: Appointments can have n records, The "SomeModel" is actually a Job. A Job can have multiple appointments. The issue I have is I want to display the next appointment in the series at a "high level overview" without loading all the, for example, 29 appointments the job has in some cases @nice_dev

Comment: @Jaquarh _A Job can have multiple appointments_ Ok, in this case, Job shares a _hasMany_ relation with the _Appointment_ model. You will need to create a custom method to fetch the next appointment and not through relations.

Comment: Yes, I have another relationship to return a HasMany but in this case, I just want one record and according to the docs and some SO questions, that can be done via HasOne. The issue is the performance: all appointments are still loaded hence the question I am asking, how can this be done in Laravel whilst maintaining performance? @nice_dev

Comment: I guess, I could remove the `nextAppointment` relation, loop through the paginated items and `load()` the HasMany relation and use `first` there?

Comment: @Jaquarh What happens if you add a `->limit(1);` at the end for your current query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `oldestOfMany()` [Link to Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many)

```
public function nextAppointment(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Appointment::class, 'some_model_id')
        ->whereNull('completed_at')
        ->oldestOfMany('starts_at');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using UUID's and I'm getting an error doing this: `SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function max(uuid) does not exist`

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL by chance?

Comment: Yes, I am using PostgreSQL :)

Comment: See the warning on the docs page. However you may also try: `->ofMany('starts_at', 'max');`

Comment: `->ofMany` still fires the same SQL exception for `max(uuid)`.

Comment: I guess that new method just doesn't play nicely with PostgreSQL sorry. Maybe something simple like `->take(1)` or `->limit(1)` ?

Comment: Thanks, the issue if I use `limit` or `take` is the fact the actual SQL does a `where in()` which means it would actually limit my result to only show the first appointment for the first job.

Comment: This may be a case where a separate query is going to be necessary then. Sorry I can't be any more help.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I have done as you said: `$paginated->setCollection(collect(array_map([$this, 'getNextAppointment'], $paginated->items())));` - The `getNextAppointment` will then run a independent SQL query to obtain the latest appointment. Thanks :)